# How can I update the System Drivers in my C:\Windows\SYSTEM32 Directory?

Tags: windows, drivers

I’ve been having trouble with random reboots for a long time. Microsoft sent me a list of drivers to update, but I can’t find any trustworthy looking links online and the vendors have not been responsive to my requests for drivers. Below is a list of the current files. I’m not entirely convinced these are all out of date or the root of my problem as Microsoft suggests, but it would still be nice to be able to update them.

```
ATI drivers:
%systemroot%\System32\DRIVERS\SECDRV.SYS    (4.3:86.0           Macrovision Corporation     -   Macrovision SECURITY Driver)
%systemroot%\System32\DRIVERS\ATI2MTAG.SYS  (6.14:10.6748       ATI Technologies Inc.       -   ATI Radeon WindowsNT Miniport Driver)
%systemroot%\System32\ATI2DVAG.DLL          (6.14:10.6748       ATI Technologies Inc.       -   ATI Radeon WindowsNT Display Driver)
%systemroot%\System32\ATI2CQAG.DLL          (6.14:10.311        ATI Technologies Inc.       -   Central Memory Manager / Queue Server Module)
%systemroot%\System32\ATIKVMAG.DLL          (6.14:10.35         ATI Technologies Inc.       -   Virtual Command And Memory Manager)

LSI Logic MegaRAID drivers:
%systemroot%\System32\DRIVERS\MRAID35X.SYS
%systemroot%\System32\DRIVERS\MEGASR.SYS
%systemroot%\System32\DRIVERS\MEGASAS.SYS   (2.24:0.32          LSI Corporation             -   MEGASAS RAID Controller Driver for Windows Vista/Server 2008 for x86)
%systemroot%\System32\DRIVERS\DCDBAS32.SYS  (5.9:2.6411         Dell Inc.                   -   Dell BASE Device Driver)
```

Comment: What model/machine is this?

Comment: What is the model of your Dell system?

Answer (score 2):

Updating your ATI video drivers is [simple enough](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) (unless your adapter is too old, then you’ll need to install the last drivers available for it).

Your MegaRAID drivers on the other hand may be a little more difficult. You should first check the Dell page for your system to see if they provide drivers for it. Otherwise, you will need to determine the make and model of the device, then find the drivers for it [at LSI](http://www.lsi.com/Search/Pages/results.aspx?k=drivers).